# Arguments for MongoDB backup with OpsManager or mongodump?

Tags: backup, mongodb, recovery, scripting

I have a replica set of two MongoDB nodes running (with an arbiter) and I am now wondering about the best backup and recovery solution. I am aware of the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/), but it does not provide me enough pro and con's for each solution. In particular, our team wants to decide between either a OpsManager-solution or a *mongodump*. I am not experienced with either of them, so could you be so kind and **please help me out with more arguments and experiences**? The following arguments I collected so far, feel free to edit them if they are not correct:

**Arguments for *mongodump* and against OpsManager**

- simpler, just a command line for a snapshot and another one for the recovery
- no additional servers and/or licenses required which is the suggested solution for OpsManager

**Arguments for OpsManager and against *mongodump***

- tested solution, provided directly by the team who developed MongoDB
- cleaner and sustainable, since it could be configured via GUI and does not require command line access
- easy logging of each backup run possible, which contrasts to *mongodump* requiring a custom (power?) shell script wrapped around

---

Related questions on Stackexchange which did not solve my issue:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555280/best-way-to-make-hot-backup-mongodbtokumx-database-instance
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502601/how-should-i-backup-mongodb-on-digitalocean
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169209/backup-mongodb-data
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458124/how-to-get-a-consistent-mongodb-backup-for-a-single-node-setup
- [Backup with mongoexport or mongodump?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107549/backup-with-mongoexport-or-mongodump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be a full answer (as others will have valid opinion) but I am ok with not getting credit.

Argument in favor of OpsManager:

- Continuous backup, you can recover up to the last committed transaction.
- You can set your retention one time and do not have to worry about it.
- You can automatically make multiple copy of your backup for redundancy.
- Restoring non production environment (DEV/QA/INT) in matter on minutes.
- mongodump excludes the content of the local database in its output which is problematic for sharded cluster and replica set.
- mongodump only captures the documents in the database in its backup data and does not include index data. mongorestore or mongod must then rebuild the indexes after restoring data.
- mongodump can adversely affect performance of the mongod. If your
  data is larger than system memory, the mongodump will push the
  working set out of memory.
- Mongodump is not suitable for large databases. This is from official documentation.

> The mongodump and mongorestore utilities work with BSON data dumps,
>   and are useful for creating backups of **small deployments**. For
>   resilient and non-disruptive backups, use a file system or block-level
>   disk snapshot function, such as the methods described in the MongoDB
>   Backup Methods document.
>
> Because mongodump and mongorestore operate by interacting with a
>   running mongod instance, they can impact the performance of your
>   running database. Not only do the tools create traffic for a running
>   database instance, they also force the database to read all data
>   through memory. When MongoDB reads infrequently used data, it can
>   evict more frequently accessed data, causing a deterioration in
>   performance for the database’s regular workload.

Comment: Thanks so much  for the quick answer. Just two immediate questions: What is the quantitative definition of "large database" (your last bullet point)? Any additional arguments in favor of *mongodump*?

Comment: Added few more points. I would not put a number here, I suggest you test in your environment.  I use mongodump for quick backup restore single collection, subset of data in dev only.